# Hadoop word count on a large file containing a single line

Tags: java, hadoop, word-count

I'm trying to run hadoop word count examples and the following is what my mapper looks like:

```
public static class TokenizerMapper
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

  private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
  private Text word = new Text();

  public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
    while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
      word.set(itr.nextToken());
      context.write(word, one);
    }
  }
}
```

This worked so far for my examples (small dataset) but when I used my actual dataset (8GB), it didn't. I think it's because of the way the text is processed. In the code snippet given, I'm pretty sure the whole string is being read into memory, which obviously won't scale very well.

> I think my problem is related to the way hadoop reads text files, it expects it to be **a** large file (in total) but it doesn't expect that a *single line* will be large.

**My question is**: what could be a good approach to have hadoop read the file chunk by chunk (so it scales and doesn't crash the RAM) and *still* perform the splitting on whitespace?